# Tibco EMS : not acknowledge message

Tags: java, tibco-ems

I have N tombcat servers listening to a Tibco EMS queue. I have to send N messages each must be treated by a specific server (message 1 must be treated by tomcat server 1, ..., message N must be treated by server N)

As messages will be received by a random machine, I need to refuse message N on server N-1 for example , and return it to queue, until it is treated by server N..

What I've done, I throw an exception on message handler when receiving a message destinated to another queue, but I don't know really if message will be returned to queue , and will be forwarded to other instances?

Is there a time / number of retry limit on Tibco EMS when not acknowledging a message?

Answer (score 2):

First : have you considered using either : A - One queue per server ? OR B - A system based on message selector ? (name of destination server N is written by the sender in a JMS property "DestName", and each Tomcat server subscribes to the same queue, but with a message selector "DestName=MyTomcatID").

If none of the above is possible, then keep in mind that [JMS transactions](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074123/java-web-development/transaction-and-redelivery-in-jms.html) MUST be used, if you want an uncommitted message to rollback to the queue... and that the next server reading is random... NOT CYCLIC.